# Running command as login shell without starting a new shell?

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to see what the output of a command would be if I were in a login shell, without having to go into a login shell. I've tried several variations of

```
zsh --login -c "alias"
```

But none of my aliases get shown; are `--login` and `-c` incompatible?

Comment: Do your login files terminate early (before setting aliases) if the shell is not interactive.  It may be working but you aren't setting the aliases, so you can't use them.  Try adding `-x` to the command line (before the `-c`).

Comment: Tried the `-x`, same result

Comment: Good; it's self-consistent.  Did you see your aliases being set?  Was `/etc/zprofile` read?  Was any other similar file read?

Comment: Here's the output : https://gist.github.com/marcusbuffett/387070b3a4742883c628679a505fc325

Comment: That's similar to what I got. How does it compare to what you get if don't specify the `-c` option?

Comment: If I don't specify `-c`, it opens a shell as usual, with all my aliases, functions, etc. defined

Comment: So you have your answer; it behaves differently. You also know what extra it does, so you can craft a command to go at the start of the `-c` command argument to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

To test the difference between `zsh --login -c "alias"` and a normal login shell, you can/should add the `-x` option to see what the shell is up to.

When I run `zsh -x --login -c "alias"`, then it processes `/etc/zprofile`.

When I run `zsh -x --login`, then it processes `/etc/zprofile` and `/etc/zshrc`.

I don't normally use `zsh`, so I don't have any personalized profile or start up file for it, but it seems plausible that it might look for (but, in my case, not find) `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshrc` too.

I created trivial versions of those files:

```
$ echo "echo in .zprofile" > ~/.zprofile
$ echo "echo in .zshrc" > ~/.zshrc
```

and sure enough, they're processed.  Further, the `-c` command with `--login` processed the `.zprofile` but did not process the `.zshrc` file.

Thus, using `-c "alias"` after the `--login` suppresses the processing of `/etc/zshrc` and `~/.zshrc`.  If you want those executed even so, you need to use something like:

```
zsh --login -c "[ -f /etc/zshrc ] && . /etc/zshrc; [ -f ~/.zshrc ] && . ~/.zshrc; alias"
```

Using `-x` to debug login processing is often informative.

It's nice that modern shells provide a command line option to induce login processing.  I still have a program (which I don't use any more) that runs a login shell the old-fashioned way, by adding a `-` before the shell name in `argv[0]`.  Thus, running `-ksh` would trigger login processing; the `login` program would run the login shell with the `-` at the start.